# Compiling library with make returns error - recompile with -fPIC (no ./configure file)

Tags: makefile, cmake, fpic

I'm trying to compile KArchive from KDE ([here](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/karchive/html/index.html)). Obviously I'm following their instructions in the install file. First thing goes well, I just have to make a directory called **build** and in there I use this:

```
cmake .. \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

Which goes well. The problem appears when I have to use **make**. After running that I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol BZ2_crc32Table can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(compress.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata.str1.1 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(decompress.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against .rodata can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(blocksort.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata.str1.1 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Now, this problem is not uncommon, but most solutions haven't worked for me.

Comment: Which solutions have you tried ? Error message is explicit, you cannot use a static lib `.a` to create a shared library `.so`. What is the output of `locate libbz2` on your computer ?

Comment: Some solutions said to use --enable-shared when running ./configure, but I don't have a configure file. I also tried to set CXXFLAGS=-fPIC in the makefile but doesn't help. The output of locate is: /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1
/usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0.6
/usr/lib64/libbz2.so
/usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1
/usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kerfuffle/kerfuffle_libbz2.so
/usr/local/lib/libbz2.a

Comment: As you have the `/usr/lib/libbz2.so.1`, you don't have to recompile your lib with `-fPIC` flag. You apparently have to correct shared lib but your linker is using a wrong one. Could you try to add the `-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/` flag to your Cmake command and see if there's any change ?

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have already found the solutions in the comments section, I take time to give you a proper answer to clarify the situation.

First of all, CMake is a great tool to generate MakeFile. You can see a CMakeLists.txt file at the root of your project where you configure all what you need to compile your project.

Then you create and go into your build directory, an type the command `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local`. The `..` in the command line is the path where you have your main CMakeLists.txt of your project. Additional flags can be added with `-DFLAG_NAME=value`.

In your case, when you compile using `make`, the problem was your linker was using a static lib instead of a dynamic lib to generate a dynamic lib (That's the error message).

Your compiler suggests to recompile the bz2 library using `-fPIC` flag (Position Independent Code).

Using the command `locate libbz2`, you told me you had the `/usr/lib/libbz2.so.1` on your computer so the problem is only a library path issue.

In order to add the path to this library, you have a CMake flag for that, as a result, the following command solve your problem:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/
```